# Use production media files in development - Django

Tags: python, django, django-filer

I have a blog made with Django (and Django-CMS). Some times, when working in development, I make some changes and it would be nice to see how those changes that I'm doing look like with the actual media files that I have in production.

So today I tried to set the `MEDIA_URL` and the `MEDIA_ROOT` settings to be the actual media URL of my production site. i.e:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'https://example.com/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'https://example.com/media/'
```

I was naively hoping to see the media files of production in development after doing this, but nope, it didn't work.

I also tried to do the the typical extending of `urlpatterns` list. i.e:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But then I read in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) that it is useless to do that if the given prefix (`MEDIA_URL`) is an URL (as in my case).

**Aditional info:** My site is hosted by PythonAnywhere, and they (pythonanywhere) serve the media files as well. The files are all public. I use [`django-filer`](https://django-filer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as my file manager. One sample of my media files: [media file](https://www.list-em.com/media/filer_public_thumbnails/filer_public/cf/8c/cf8cf6ef-fa0c-49b5-ab49-a529916f2dce/top-7-epic-halo-mainline-video-games-you-should-play-header.jpg__800x450_q85_crop_subsampling-2.jpg)

Anyway, is this possible to achieve? If so, what am I missing?